# Using ArrayField and adding 'django_postgres_extensions' to INSTALLED_APPS causes LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using postgres with Django and one of the fields in the model should be an Array. When I was trying to use it I was recommended that I use "django_postgres_extensions" so I ran "pip install django_postgres_extensions" and even added 'django_postgres_extensions' to INSTALLED_APPS to settings.py.

```
from django_postgres_extensions.models.fields import ArrayField
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Wanted(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, default="default")
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, default="default")
    encodings = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=[], form_size=10, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="wanted/", null=True, blank=True)
```

Each time I run "python manage.py runserver", I get the following error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\Desktop\KYOKO\Work\Talan\GitProject\IBCS\server\src\models\models.py", line 80, in <module>
    class Wanted(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 156, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 733, in contribute_to_class
    self.set_attributes_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\postgres\fields\array.py", line 76, in set_attributes_from_name
    self.base_field.set_attributes_from_name(name)
TypeError: set_attributes_from_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'admin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\Desktop\KYOKO\Work\Talan\GitProject\IBCS\server\src\IBCS\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 529, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "C:\Users\Kyoko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

Edit: INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'django_postgres_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'models',
    'identity',
    'agents',
    'admincp',
]
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? You could simply use the default support for PostgreSQL fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: Could you post the INSTALLED_APPS settings?

Comment: Django version 2.2